# MySql Trigger Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have written the code for trigger the function to update my table after inset event complete.

This is my code,

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `first_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH
ROW UPDATE table1
SET test= "verified"
```

Error Message I got it,

**Error:** Can't update table 'table1' in stored function/trigger because it is
already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

How to solve this error?

Comment: Why not set test in the insert?

Answer (score 1):

You must alter the value which would be saved into the table. Of course you must do this before the saving, i.e. in BEFORE INSERT trigger.

To refer to the value for the row which is currently inserted you must refer to it using the alias NEW which acts as pseudo-table which contains one row which is inserted now.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `first_trigger` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `table1`
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.test= 'verified';
```